# SQL*Loader handling multiple values in a single column

Tags: oracle11g, sqlplus, sql-loader

I have a CSV data file containing data that I want to load into my database structure. A sample data in that CSV file is something like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, "val1,val2,val3,val4,...", col5, col6, "val1,val2,val3,...", col8
```

As you can see in the above scenario the data is delimited by a comma and the columns c4 and c7 are enclosed in inverted commas and they contain multiple values each. Basically, I am trying to map these multiple values into many-to-many relationships. for example, consider that every line in the above CSV file represents a movie and col4 contains genres to that movie. Now I have a table named as "Genre" in my schema and another table "Movie_Genre" so while loading the data I want to load these genres of col4 into the "Genre" table making sure a value doesn't repeat and at the same time I want to map the movies stored in "Movies" table with genres stored in  "Genres" table through the use of "Movie_Genres" table which contains the "movie_id" & "genre_id".

How would I achieve this using SQL Loader on SQLPLUS Oracle 11g windows platform?

Comment: Load data as is to a staging table and do process with sql queries.

Comment: @Serg Well, I guess that might be possible because I haven't tried that yet but can't I achieve this using a SQL loader control file?

Comment: This design violates first normal form of data normalization which states that a column must contain only a single value.  This will cause query nightmares in the future.  To fix and create a many to many relationship, you take the PK of both entities and put them together to create an associative table. This table will only have attributes if they describe the association itself.  Do some searching, it will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'nameoffile.csv'
INSERT INTO TABLE Billing
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
col1,
col2
)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer?

Comment: The optionally enclosed by clause will keep the values together but as I mention above this design is bad and will cause you problems down the road.